# Formating and partioning a large Harddrive

Tags: partitioning

I would like to be able to use my entire 3.0 TB HD. I installed it into a new 'escaping win' Ubuntu box that was already running a SSD. After 25 years of Win , I ended up having to re-install Ubuntu several times. My 3.0 TB drive only let me make an 800 GB partition even though it shows the remainder as Free Space.

Comment: Are you using gpt partitioning?  Use gparted and select gpt under device, advanced & select gpt over msdos(MBR) default partitioning.... Or
`sudo parted /dev/sdb mklabel gpt` If manually partitioning best to include both an ESP - efi system partition and a bios_grub partition as first two partitions. Even if currently a data only drive. Later you may want an install and then can boot either UEFI or BIOS as you have necessary partitions. I like to have an Install on every drive, even if smaller / and not really used, but just for emergency.

Comment: The following link may help you. Please notice that it is [probably] enough to create a GUID partition table, GPT, and let Ubuntu create partitions automatically unless you want 'Something else', [help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Gparted in live mode, to format and then make an new partition using the full size of the hard drive and then re-install?

Comment: This isn't an answer, it's a comment.

Comment: I ran Ubuntu in live CD mode and ran Gparted. I managed to format the drive in question. I then reinstalled Ubuntu on /sda/ & have a good as new 3 TB /sdb/ for data. Lesson learned.